# Python: obtain multidimensional matrix as results from a function

Tags: python

I have a multi-inputs function, say:

```
def bla(a, b):
    f = a + b
    return f
```

When I do something like

```
import numpy as np
bla(np.asarray([0.2,0.4]), np.asarray([2,4]))
```

The result is:

```
array([ 2.2,  4.4])
```

However, I want `bla` to be applied to each possible pair of my inputs(`bla(0.2, 2)`, `bla(0.2, 4)`, `bla(0.4, 2)`, `bla(0.4, 4)`) and obtain the final result as a 2-D matrix. In this example, I want the result to be:

```
array([[2.2, 4.2],
[2.4, 4.4]
])
```

How can I do this?
My original problem is that I have a function with three variables and one output, then I want to call the function by entering vectors for each variable so that I obtain a 3-D matrix as a result

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do more clearly?

Comment: You want matrix multiplication?

Comment: Where do 2.3 and 4.3 come from? Do you mean 2.4 and 4.4?

Comment: Could you please explain the line `**dimension = number of inputs and the (i,j) element of the matrix is bla(ai,bj)**` more precisely?

Its still so unclear ...

Comment: Sorry for my unclear explanation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided your function `bla` can accept arrays instead of scalars, you could use
[meshgrid](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) to prepare the inputs so that `bla(A, B)` returns the desired output:

```
import numpy as np
def bla(a, b):
    f = a + b
    return f

A, B = np.meshgrid([0.2,0.4], [2,4], sparse=True)
bla(A, B)
```

yields

```
array([[ 2.2,  2.4],
       [ 4.2,  4.4]])
```

Comment: Thank you for your simple idea!

Comment: While using mesgrid, sometimes memory errors occur if a and b are big and there are three or more variables. Do you have other solutions?

Comment: @gravedigger: If you use  `sparse=True` then `np.meshgrid` will return a "sparse grid" which will consume much less memory.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want to do this without modifying `bla()`, but for your example at least that's where the change must be:

```
def bla(a, b):
    return np.asarray(a+n for n in b)
```

This operates on array `a` with **each element** of `b`, and builds an array with the results. Your example looks a little random (how did you get those `.3` fractional parts?), but I'm guessing this is what you're trying to get at.